# Can ping and traceroute but not able to browse certain websites

Tags: network-manager, dns, browser, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved

- I can `ping` and `traceroute` with the help of `mtr -rw` but I **simply cannot browse** certain websites. I have found no common denominator between these websites to understand where the problem lies.
- The only way to browse these websites is via a Tor Browser and no amount of flushing browser cache, changing browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Brave), private windows *etc.* does the trick.
- I am on 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver) and I have tried a lot of stuff from various SO posts but to no avail. I will update my post based on any pertinent comments.

Here are **some of the websites** (found by pure luck) that I am unable to access :

1. https://www.leboncoin.fr
2. https://www.linuxmint.com
3. https://www.protonmail.com

Otherwise I am able to access every other website, which is driving me crazy !

Here is an example of a `ping` + `traceroute` with the help of `mtr -rw` :

```
~$ mtr -rw www.linuxmint.com
Start: 2021-01-30T20:17:22+0100
HOST: SIT                                   Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- _gateway                               0.0%    10    0.9   0.8   0.7   1.0   0.1
  2.|-- 194.149.169.174                        0.0%    10   28.5  28.5  28.0  29.2   0.4
  3.|-- ???                                   100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  4.|-- ???                                   100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  5.|-- be2103.ccr42.par01.atlas.cogentco.com 10.0%    10   28.6  28.8  28.3  29.4   0.4
  6.|-- be3685.ccr52.lhr01.atlas.cogentco.com  0.0%    10   35.6  36.1  35.3  37.1   0.5
  7.|-- be3672.agr21.lhr01.atlas.cogentco.com  0.0%    10   36.5  36.5  35.9  36.8   0.3
  8.|-- sucuri.demarc.cogentco.com             0.0%    10   35.6  35.6  34.1  36.4   0.7
  9.|-- cloudproxy10053.sucuri.net             0.0%    10   36.2  35.9  34.7  36.7   0.7
```

And here is a screenshot from a private window in Firefox :
[image: Screenshot from a private window in Firefox]

---

**EDIT 1** :
I have another laptop with Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS installed and with all packages up to date. Previously, I used this system as an independent trial to check whether the ISP could be blocking these websites (I also tried it again now). The result : **I cannot browse these websites** but I can `ping` and `traceroute` them !

But I see no reasonable explanation for an ISP in **Europe** to block https://www.linuxmint.com or https://www.leboncoin.fr !

---

**EDIT 2** :
It has been suggested in the comments that I reset my modem/router to factory settings for resolving the issue.

The problem is that I have an ADSL modem which has no reset button on it. I can only set some other options from my subscriber account which is available only from the ISP's website !

**Note 1** : When I connect to my company VPN for work (using Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Version 4.6.04056) and after having used it for a few hours, I can access these websites again ! After work, when I shut off the VPN, these websites remain accessible. I have not yet managed to determine the cut-off when these specific websites become accessible. This has "*convinced me*" that it is not a modem/router issue.

**Note 2** : However, after a day's work (*i.e.* with the VPN switched off and with all websites accessible), if I were to switch the ADSL modem off and on, I loose access to these websites (and only these) once again ! This has "*convinced me*" that it could still be a (very weird) modem/router issue.

---

**EDIT 3** :
Here is some more info based on comments by @ubfan1. I installed the `libnss-resolve` package. I didn't find any `NXDOMAIN` errors in the `dmesg` output.

```
~$ dmesg | grep NXDOMAIN
~$
```

And just in case, here are my `resolv.conf` contents :

```
~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
~$ 
~$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Dec  5 11:25 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

---

Comment: Do other systems on that network have similar issues with the same sites?

Comment: @user535733 : see EDIT 1 above

Comment: Since both systems exhibit the same symptoms, the problem is neither Ubuntu system. Look to your router and your modem. Coincidentally, I had a similar problem recently. I was able to plug directly into the modem (bypassing the router) -- problem vanished. Restore the router -- problem returned. Power-cycled the router -- problem returned. Factory-reset the router -- problem vanished. Not saying you have an identical problem, but you can see the troubleshooting method to isolate the fault.

Comment: @user535733 : see EDIT 2 above

Comment: Take a look at bugs 1727237,1805027,1804487,1624071,1647031.  I had to add package libnss-resolve on earlier releases than 20.04, and still have it, but the problem has been rare.  The UDP fallback for DNS is temporary, so comes and goes. Check dmesg output for NXDOMAIN errors.

Comment: @ubfan1 : see EDIT 3 above. I am afraid I have not understood all the https://bugs.launchpad.net issues you have referred to. Also, I have not noticed any improvement after having installed the libnss-resolve package.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has a bug for (some) cached sites.  When you see that screen, type ctrl-shift R to reload from the actual web site, and you should get your page.

Comment: I am not aware of the bug you mention but just in case I am on Firefox 84.0.2 (64-bit) and ctrl-shift R did nothing more. Similar inaccessibility with Chrome and Brave for these specific websites which are only accessible to me via a Tor browser, which is overkill.